# In Visual Studio 2010 how to get Solution Explorer to highlight the file you are viewing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I like the NaviateTo option in Visual Studio 2010, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get VS to highlight the current file I am viewing.

Its one thing to navigate to the file, but I also want to know where the file is and not have to dig around for it.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436222/how-to-locate-a-file-in-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I assume you mean, highlight in Solution Explorer.

For that, you can go to:

Tools -> Options -> Projects And Solutions

Check the `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer` option

Answer (score 17):

Go to Tools - Options.
Under Projects and Solutions - General.
Check the 'Track Active Item in Solution Explorer' checkbox.

Comment: LOL.  I feel a little guilty.  I think anyone upvoting should upvote both of our answers.  :)

Comment: Just added one to even it up a little :)

Answer (score 3):

Resharper offers the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut which will switch the focus to the current file in the Solution Explorer as it isn't always obvious when tracking. (This shortcut requires tracking to be enabled)

Comment: Actually I find with R# 8 in VS 2010 that I *do not* need to enable tracking first.  This is really helpful, as I don't want the tracking constantly moving my Solution Explorer, but still want the functionality on demand.