# How to locate a file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a huge solution with multiple projects. Sometime I need to navigate to a file in **Solution Explorer**. Using the VS 2010 '**Navigate To**' feature I can open any file by name in Visual Studio 2010 but I want to be able to select the file in **Solution Explorer** as well?

Comment: The question was about VS2010, but in case somebody is looking at VS2013: Check out Ctrl-; for a find in the Solution Explorer or Ctrl-, for the VS2012/13 "Navigate To" feature.

Comment: For a native way for VS 2012 and above, check out Aaron Carlson's answer below.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and I was able to get this functionality through adding the free extension CodeMaid. Ctrl+M, Ctrl+F to trigger the action.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

There's an option to track the active (open and viewed) item in the solution explorer.  If the file is in view, the file in the solution explorer will be selected.

Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

Comment: This settings causes that project and solution nodes are constantly expanded as I open files. After 15 minutes of working on bigger project, I have so many nodes expanded that solution explorer becomes unsuable. [DPack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436222/how-to-locate-a-file-in-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010/4747759#4747759) solution is IMO better.

Comment: @karel-kral, I've added an answer that uses a Macro to toggle this setting which works around this expanded node issue.

Comment: the resharper or dpack solutions listed here get round the problem Martin mentions and make this answer not the preferred option if you have either of the others available to you.

Comment: For VS2012+ @Aaron's answer is the best. No installing things Ctrl + [,s

Comment: He said he only wanted to track the file "Sometimes" not all the time. Aaron Carlson's answer should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this simply expands the massive list of "External Dependencies" instead of actually opening the project that contains that header file.

Answer (score 180):

VS2012 added a new command called `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument`.  The default shortcut for c# is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>

This command will navigate to the active file in the Solution Explorer.

Also, it seems that you need to have the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option turned off.

Comment: Massive oversight that this didn't go into Visual Studio 6.0. Or even earlier. WTF.

Comment: Thanks! In my **VS2013**, `Ctrl`+`[`,`S`was default set to check out file and `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument` was not configured.

Comment: Please note that this option is only available if you are already in the solution explorer context. I mapped this command to the following shortcut: `Ctrl` + `.`. Now i can use `Ctrl` + `0` to navigate to solution explorer and then use my assigned shortcut.

Comment: @krypru, I've been using VS2015 for a while and it still works for me.  Maybe it's not mapped to the same shortcut in your environment?

Comment: This is the correct answer, works in VS2015 and VS2017

Comment: FYI, don't need to remember the shortcut key:  Solution Explorer (I'm in VS 2015) has an icon at top (double arrows) that does "Sync with Active Document".

Comment: VS 2017 added a "ReSharper" keyboard mapping under Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard. This maps built-in VS functionality to the equivalent ReSharper shortcut. Once you set this, you can use the `Shift` + `Alt` + `L` shortcut.

Comment: Yes, this is best solution than Dpack, resharper and "tick track active doc"

Comment: This is good. What I liked even better was remaping `ctrl + [ + s` to resharpers command: `shift + alt + L`. It's more intuitive. The keyboard command is: `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument`

Comment: For all of you using german keyboard layout it's `Ctrl + ß + s`

Answer (score 127):

With **ReSharper installed** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will find the current file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2008+.

Comment: when you track you don't need this shortcut.

Comment: It is a Reshaper command. Works for me with Visual Studio 2010 with ReSharper installed.

Comment: +1; @DavutGürbüz Sometimes you need this to kick Visual Studio 2012 into start auto-tracking again. Every once in a while (despite the checkbox "... Track Active ..." being checked, Visual Studio 2012 stops tracking. This ReSharper shortcut will reenable this without having to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers I see . I've been using DPack extension. It is very lite and easy to use. You just right click the file tab and choose Locate on the Solution Explorer. I strongly recommend it. It works all versions of VS. ReSharper is also good but we don't prefer. Because we don't use most of its features. It makes VS heavier.

Tracking makes solution explorer messy. DPack is the best one.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747759/413032

Comment: Tracking does not have to be enabled for Shift+Alt+L to work. At least not in VS 2010, which I am using.

Comment: This works for me without tracking enabled in VS 2015 using R# 9.2.

Answer (score 40):

I found the track option to be a little annoying.

I prefer to use **[DPack](https://github.com/sergey-visual-studio/dpack)**. It contain "Locate In Solution Explorer" operation, plus many other features (some are less powerful in VS2010, like their browsers), and **it's free**.

[image]

Note that **[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)** also have the locate feature that works batter than DPack's (in some cases, DPack's locate won't work if the file is collapsed behind folders), but you don't want to [buy ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/index.jsp) only for this [feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html).

Comment: The most hassle-free solution ("Track Active Item" is irritating and ReSharper isn't free).

Comment: @IanKemp, it's a matter of taste. IMO the tracking is annoying because: 1. sometimes I like the sln tree to stay focus on a particular node. 2. after a while, the sln tree gets completely expanded.

Comment: i have installed and worked good for me, thank you!

Answer (score 29):

[Brian Schmitt](http://www.brianschmitt.com/) has a great [Locate File in Solution Explorer – Visual Studio Macro](http://www.brianschmitt.com/locate-file-in-solution-explorer-visual/) post for this. The macro is extremely simple and quick. Basically it toggles the setting

```
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer
```

so that the current file ends up selected in the Solution Explorer but, because it is not left on, you don't get irritated by Solution Explorer nodes being expanded for all the files you access.

```
Public Sub LocateFileInSolutionExplorer()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.SolutionExplorer")
End Sub
```

[Bind a Keyboard ShortCut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx) to this custom macro to effectively create what should be a built-in Visual Studio feature.

Comment: This really works in VS 2010 and is easier to setup than you think (tips for adding macro: http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/6).

Comment: The link posted in the first line of answer is broken. Can you fix it please ?

Comment: @TyagiAkhilesh - note that this answer (adding your own macro) is only needed if you are still using VS 2010. Newer versions have a command built in.

Answer (score 19):

If you have ReSharper and want to add "Locate in Solution Explorer" to the tab's context menu:

1. Go to Tools -> Customize -> Commands -> Context Menu
2. Select "Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window".
3. Click "Add Command".
4. Choose "Resharper" -> "ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer" (in VS2019, the category name was changed to "Extensions")
5. "OK" -> "Close"

Now, when right click on any tab and you'll see a new option: Locate in Solution Explorer.

**UPDATE:**

Following the comment from @jeremy-paskali, you can set a keyboard shortcut for this command:

1. Go to Tools -> Customize -> "Keyboard..."
2. Search for "ReSharper.ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer" in the "Show commands containing" field and select it.
3. Review the currently assigned shortcuts in the drop down below.
4. Make any changes, if needed.
5. "OK" -> "Close"

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, if you then click the "Keyboard..." button at the bottom of the "Customize" window, you will be taken to the Options -> Environment -> Keyboard dialog.  In this dialog, you can navigate to "ReSharper.ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer" and find or change the keyboard shortcut to this command.  I discovered that my VS2015 was set to "Shift+Alt+L" and it works!

Comment: Chiming in more than two years later to say the context menu trick still works with VS 2017 and R# 2018.2. Thanks for this!

Comment: If trying out `Shift+Alt+L` didn't work for you in VS2019, then this surely does the job.

Answer (score 18):

Visual Studio 2012 has a new shortcut `Ctrl [, S`. Yes you have to type `Ctrl [` and then release and then immediately type `S` (or click the little sync icon at the top of Solution Explored). It will synchronize to the item.

Of course you can change the shortcut. I think I'll try `Alt+L` for locate.

If you want to change the shortcut, it's command name under `Options\Environment\Keyboard` is `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument`.

Usually this is more useful than always tracking, which in older versions always was a disaster because it would track 100 items in a row and then be jumping all over the place...

Comment: Great !!!  In my VS2012 the combination keys are `Ctrl+', s`. So you must change `[` with quote `'`.  I hope this help someone.

Comment: _"or click the little sync icon at the top of Solution Explore"_ To me the easiest way to accomplish this in the newer versions of VS. Nice one!

Comment: Thanks @mrt!  I totally glossed over that in this answer; but you saved me from having to do some weird customization steps (or remember an obscure shortcut)...!  That button should be called out more explicitly in this answer :)

Answer (score 11):

I know its little too late, but hope it helps someone else. The best option now is to install Microsoft Visual Studio add on called - Productivity Power Tools.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

With this comes "Solution Navigator" (alternative to Solution Explorer, with a lot of benefits) - which then you can use to filter the files to only show "Open". You can even filter files to show "Edited" and "Unsaved".

Comment: I am using VS 2012 and the Power Tools. I do not see a Solution Navigator anywhere. Would you like to elaborate on the subject? Like tell where exactly the Solution Navigator is found.

Comment: Edited. Microsoft planned on doing it - but ended up migrating only parts of it. I was disappointed that they left out this one as well.

Answer (score 6):

> In the event you want to only track the current file through a
>   keyboard shortcut - the activity is
>   "View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer"  (assign keys here -> Tools -
>   Options - Environment - Keyboard)

[Credit (James' comment)](http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2008/11/26/visual-studio-show-active-file-in-solution-explorer/)

This worked for me

Comment: Note this toggles the option "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer". If you don't want to keep that option ( because it's annoying ) you have to type the assigned shortcut keys twice: once to turn it on ( finds the selected item ) and then again to turn off the option.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There are several build-in ways you can accomplish this nowadays:

1. **Configure VS to track the active item in Solution Explorer**: This can be accomplished by selecting "Track active item in Solution
   Explorer" at

> Tools > Settings > Projects and Solutions > General

[image]

---

2. **Use "Sync with active document":** This can be accomplished in 2 ways.

   - Firing the `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument` command by using the default key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> if you happen to be using an AZERTY keyboard like me.
   - By using the "Sync with active document" button on top of the Solution Explorer. The button looks like 2 apposing arrows on top of each other.

     If you're version is older then `VS2019 Version 16.10.2` then this button looks like this:

     [image]

     From `VS2019 Version 16.10.2` onwards this button will look like this:

     [image]

     And yet again Microsoft has changed the button icon in more recent versions of VS 2022:

     [image]

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can turn on the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" option. This will mean whenever you switch between documents the new document gets selected in Solution Explorer. This can be irritating if your solution has lots of folders, because as you move around files in your solution all the folders will be left open.

Visual Studio 2012 introduced the new "Sync with Active Document" feature. Three is a button for it at the top of Solution Explorer, or you can use the shortcut `Ctrl + [, S`.

[image: screenshot of sync with active document button]

Comment: Hasn't this already been covered adequately by existing answers from years ago?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually built in to visual studio without the need for ReSharper (which I love BTW).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/29/track-active-item-in-solution-explorer-vstipproj0011.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the file in the solution explorer on command and don't want to install anything then I would recommend this [**macro**](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/visual-studio-macro-track-item-in-solution-explorer-on-demand/).

I've tested it, setting the shortcut to Alt+T, and I can confirm that it works with VS 2010.

Thanks to Dan Vanderboom for writing it.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017 using a French AZERTY keyboard the command is the same as stated by Aaron Carlson but the keyboard shortcut is different.

The AZERTY keyboard shortcut to navigate to the active file for c# is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

I checked the shortcut hadn't changed for QWERTY users in VS2017 on this page
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn’t offer an easy way to locate the current file you’re editing in the Solution Explorer on demand. You can set the solution explorer to always stay in sync with this simple setting:

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General. Check “Track active item in Solution Explorer”.

Thanks to [Cory House](https://www.bitnative.com/2012/05/01/locate-current-file-in-solution-explorer/)