# VS 2012: Scroll Solution Explorer to current file

Tags: file, visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

VS2010 had the feature that viewing a file would automatically cause Solution Explorer to scroll to that file.

With VS2012, viewing different files from within the IDE no longer scrolls and select the file in Solution Explorer automatically.

Is it possible to get this feature back? Is there a setting somewhere? If so, how/where?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436222/how-to-locate-a-file-in-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: use "Find in Solution Explorer" extension (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2fc1e94-b85c-4a15-8569-390db1e04f47) which Adds the "Find in Solution Explorer" menu command to the context menu of open document tabs.

Comment: If you have ReSharper, I posted a context menu solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32238950/264672)

Answer (score 850, accepted):

Yes, you can find that under

> Tools - > Options - > Projects and Solutions - > Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

It's off by default (as you've noticed), but once it's on, Solution Explorer will expand folders and highlight the current document as you switch between files.

Comment: Awesome!  Microsoft should let users know when they turn a feature off.  it was much missed yestdrday.  Thanks!

Comment: Although I checked it, It doesn't work in most cases. I think it is buggy in VS 2012. When the solution explorer is "Auto Hide" mode (or unpinned) , it looses the active file position and moves the top! It is really disgusting :(

Comment: Upvoted! This is on by default in 2010 and I HATE it! Luckily, you can turn it off using the method above in 2010. Thanks!

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej, there is a bug reported regarding that matter https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777003/solution-explorer-being-in-the-auto-hide-mode-doesnt-stay-in-sync-with-the-active-item

Comment: Setting doesn't work correctly when the solution explorer is docked as a document either, UNLESS the document is visible in a split or separate window group.

Comment: Welcome to Visual Studio land where the bugs are reported and then never fixed! Seriously, I'm seeing this bug today and it was reported 2 years ago.

Comment: If Visual Studio was perfect then who would buy Resharper?

Comment: If you've got >200 projects in your solution this one is just nice.

Comment: Been looking for an option like this for ages! thanks!

Comment: This solution applies to VS Pro 2019 Version 16.9.4 as well

Comment: in VS 2022 
Tools - > Options - > Projects and Solutions - >General -> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

Answer (score 334):

If you need one-off sync with the solution pane, then there is new command "Sync with Active Document" (default shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>). Explained here: [Visual Studio 2012 New Features: Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/zainnab/visual-studio-2012-new-features-solution-explorer)

Comment: This also works in Visual Studio 2013. Even the Express editions.

Comment: This should be available as an option in the context menu as well!

Comment: I learned from another answer in this thread that there is also an icon along the top of the solution explorer which will "sync with active document."  Not sure if this was introduced in 2012 or 2013, but it works in 2013.

Comment: In VS2012(not tested in 2013, 2015) one can use either the "Track Active ..." option or the shortcut/icon. Both are not possible. You will get message Keyboard combination is bound to command (SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument) which is not currently available.

Comment: YMMV, but I find the default key shortcut cumbersome to press, so I mapped this command to the F6 key instead. Works great for me.

Comment: I use VS2015 + ReSharper on Win10 and this is the only way that works now. If you're willing to use a different shortcut, look for "SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument" on Keyboard options.

Comment: I just changed the assignment to be alt + shift + l to match JetBrains Rider

Answer (score 119):

If you have ReSharper installed clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will move focus to the current file in Solution Explorer.

Active Item Tracking will also need to be enabled as described in the accepted answer

> Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

Comment: @Joe : Sarah did not mention whether she is using ReSharper or not so I would disagree

Comment: this should be the correct answer. much more pratical and generic.

Comment: It isn't the correct answer if you aren't using resharper.

Comment: @RicardoParro: how can it be *more* generic when it depends on an expensive third party add-on?

Comment: The question was about Visual Studio. People who use Resharper basically live in a whole different world, so this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In 2015 at least, you can assign the ReSharper shortcut to that action, even without ReSharper. Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument

Comment: The advice "Active Item Tracking will also need to be enabled as described in the accepted answer" is wrong! The purpose of shift/alt/L is to highlight the current item in the solution explorer when automatic active item tracking is disabled. If you have Active Item Tracking enabled then you don't need to click shift/alt/L as the current item will be automatically selected.

Answer (score 53):

There are many ways to do this:

**Go to current File once:**

- **Visual Studio 2013**

  VS 13 has it's own shortcut to do this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>, Release both keys, Press the <kbd>S</kbd> key)

  You can edit this default shortcut, if you are searching for `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument` in your `Keyboard Settings` (Tools->Options->Enviornment->Keyboard)

  In addition there is also a new icon in the Solution Explorer, more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771877/2167804).

  [image: Sync with Active Document Button in VS2013 - Solution Explorer]
- **Visual Studio 2012**

  If you use VS 2012, there is a great plugin to add this [new functionality](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/291836cc-febe-44ad-86b0-b745485110e7) from VS2013 to VS2012: . The default shortcut is <kbd>strg</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd>. I think this one is the best, as navigating to the solution explorer is mapped to <kbd>strg</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd>.
- **Resharper**

  If you use **Resharper** try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

  *This is a nice mapping as you can use <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for navigating to the solution explorer*

**Track current file all the time:**

- **Visual Studio >= 2012**:

  If you like to track your current file in the solution explorer all the time, you can use the solution from the accepted answer (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer), but I think this can get very annoying in large projects.

Comment: For the non-Germans reading this answer, replace `Strg`  with `Ctrl` & `ü` with `;` for the VS2012 solution.

Comment: I find this answer the best, (except using steuern instead of control and the other non-english keyboard shortcuts)

Comment: On Visual Studio 2017 use: ``Ctrl + `, S`` :)

Answer (score 31):

If you don't have ReSharper installed and still want to use the shortcut `Shift`+`Alt`+`L` to move focus to the current file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 then please follow these steps:

1. Go to Tools->Options and search for "Keyboard" in the Search Options textbox:

[image]

2. In the Show commands containing box type "solutionexplorer" and then in the list below look for the SyncWithActiveDocument command:
   [image]
3. Click in textbox under "Press short keys" label and press: `Shift`+`Alt`+`L` and click the Assign button and you are done:
   [image]

To verify open any file in Visual Studio and press the shortcut keys `Shift`+`Alt`+`L` and you'll see the file in the solution explorer. Enjoy!

Comment: NB: for VS2012 under the Visual C++ 6 scheme, `Shift + Alt + L` is used for Edit.LineCut (cf. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 31):

It is possible in VSS by three ways.

1. You can click on `Active sync` icon on Solution Explorer.

[image: VSS Active sync with icon in solution Explorer]

2. By selecting Active sync checkbox in Tools (***Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General***). In that check the Track Active Item in Solution Explorer Checkbox. When you select a file in the main window, it will automatically navigate to active file in the Explorer.

[image: VSS_Tools_Active_sync]

3. By using the Shortcut key (*`Ctrl`* + *`[`* + *`S`*), you can able to navigate to active Item.

***Note: Either 1 or 2 only works in a mean time.***. So You have to use either 1st or 2nd.

Answer (score 17):

I've found the `Sync with Active Document` button in the solution explorer to be the the most effective  (this may be a vs2013 feature!)

[image]

Comment: Previously it was working but now *Sync with Active Document* is not working for me. I disabled and enable it using `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"`

Answer (score 8):

Tools => Options => Projects and Solutions

Here check the highlighted checkbox!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On **Visual Studio 2017**, the shortcut is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I also love that solution much!