# track active item in solution explorer ONLY on demand

Tags: visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using VS 2010, 2012 & 2013.

Usually I don't want the IDE to auto-focus on the item in solution explorer but sometimes it's useful.

Is there any keyboard shortcut or a menu option to navigate to the file in solution explorer on demand?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [visual studio 2012 scroll solution explorer to current file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682656/visual-studio-2012-scroll-solution-explorer-to-current-file)

Comment: If you wrote it as an answer I'd select it, but here I can't :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For VS 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017:
 "Sync with Active Document" (default shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>).

Comment: This still works in VS 2022.

Answer (score 9):

I know your question refers to 2010, 2012 & 2013, but VS 2017 has a button on the solution explorer to sync with active document:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools/Options/Enviroment/keyboard look for View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer and assign the shortcut that you want.

Here I needed to remove the shortcut first, because the ctrl+shift+t was already assigned.

Of course, you can assign other shortcut.

[image: steps]

Comment: This setting is not a one off, it turns it permanently on or off (basically by ticking or unticking the Track Active item setting).