# ReSharper Shift+Alt+L (go to open file) not working in 2015 with .resx?

Tags: resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2015, resx

I'm wondering if this is just my ReSharper setup, but as of updating to Visual Studio 2015 with ReSharper Ultimate 9.1.3, using the Shift+Alt+L shortcut while editing a .resx in the designer does nothing.

Has anybody else experienced this, and is there any config that will get this working or is it a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

This was caused (for me anyway) because my keyboard mapping had magically changed back to UK mapping from US (I want US).

The other day I had another issue that caused Resharper key mappings to go awry and followed some advice on another post (I can't find it at the moment) that want along the lines of:

- Open Tools > Options > Keyboard and hit Reset
- Open Resharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus, select "Visual Studio" and hit "Apply Scheme"

This should wrest control from Resharper back to Visual Studio and give Resharper the freedom it needs to wrest control back from VS.. ugh, but it worked

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this without any luck. The problem I have is specific to the .resx editor in Visual Studio 2015. I tried it out on a colleagues machine and it has the exact same issue, so I believe it's a resharper bug.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree there is something a little off with Resharper and VS2015

Comment: Still running into this sometimes here in the future (with VS 2017). Your second suggestion (via Resharper menu) worked for me.

Comment: They are actually two parts of the same process. Glad to hear you've got it fixed though!

Comment: this has also worked for ctrl+shit+t "go to file", thank you @PaulCarroll

Answer (score 6):

Maybe have a look to [Stackoverflow - How to locate a file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849401/10655742).

Tools (in Menu) -> Options -> Keyboard -> goto input `Show commands containing` and type **SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument**. Goto `Press Shortcut Keys` and press `Shift` + `Alt` + `L` click on `Assign` button.

You may get a warning that the shortcut is already in use.

Comment: To make sure this works I unassigned all other shortcuts that used "Shift+Alt+L"

Comment: The shortcut `CTRL + ALT + L` was by default assigned to `View.SolutionExplorer` in my VS 2022. If you can't find the current command where the hotkey is assigned to there's a Shortcut Browser in ReSharper under: Extensions > ReSharper > Options > Keyboard > Shortcut Scheme > Usability > Enable Shortcut Browser (experimental) [Press left Ctrl key 3 times within 1,5 seconds to show up]